# VBA dynamic ListBox

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim j As Integer
Dim Funds(1000)

CD_Date = Cells(1, 4)

Range("A2").Select

i = 1

Do
Funds(i) = UCase(ActiveCell.Value)
i = i + 1
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop Until ActiveCell.Value = ""

MyFolder = "C:\windows\"

r = 0

For k = 1 To i - 1

MyFile = Dir$(MyFolder & "*" & Funds(k) & "*")
Do While MyFile <> ""
    datka = FileDateTime(MyFolder & MyFile)
    If Format(datka, "yymmdd") = Format(CD_Date, "yymmdd") Then
        With UserForm1.ListBox1
            .AddItem
            .List(r, 0) = Funds(k)
            .List(r, 1) = MyFile
            r = r + 1
        End With
    End If
    MyFile = Dir$
Loop

Next k

Range("A2").Select


End Sub
```

Code works perfectly, but it doesn't change dynamically when I move `CD_Date` for prior day or current - 2. It always add item for entered date and only for first run. When I change date in cell it always return me list from first initialize. It resets when I close file and open it again, each time for different date. Is it possible to modify my code that it will be filling dynamically after I change `CD_Date` or when someone add file to the folder?? I want to avoid closing and opening macro over and over just to get actual data :(

Answer (score 0):

You could add in a loop to remove all items from the ListBox before the point in your code where items are added to effectively refresh it each time. To do this you are looking for something like:

```
With UserForm1.ListBox1
    For i = 1 to .ListCount
        .RemoveItem(0) 
    Next i
End With
```

In your code it seems like each time you open the form you only want one item in the ListBox, so although the loop here is unnecessary its a good practice to remember. Try placing this in your module just before you add the item:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim j As Integer
Dim Funds(1000)

CD_Date = Cells(1, 4)

Range("A2").Select

i = 1

Do
Funds(i) = UCase(ActiveCell.Value)
i = i + 1
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop Until ActiveCell.Value = ""

MyFolder = "C:\windows\"

r = 0

For k = 1 To i - 1

MyFile = Dir$(MyFolder & "*" & Funds(k) & "*")
Do While MyFile <> ""
    datka = FileDateTime(MyFolder & MyFile)
    If Format(datka, "yymmdd") = Format(CD_Date, "yymmdd") Then
        With UserForm1.ListBox1
            For i = 1 to .ListCount 'Here
                .RemoveItem(0) 
            Next i
            .AddItem
            .List(r, 0) = Funds(k)
            .List(r, 1) = MyFile
            r = r + 1
        End With
    End If
    MyFile = Dir$
Loop

Next k

Range("A2").Select


End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, it didn't worked. When I put it at the beginning `.ListCount` is empty, when I put it at the end it remove each added item and `Listbox` is always empty.

Comment: @DominikRuczajewski The loop based on .ListCount will only run when there are items in the ListBox. Please see the addition I have made to my answer and give this a try.

Comment: `Could not set the List property. Invalid property array index.` on second loop.

Comment: I've noticed when I run macro with debugging it always return value in Listbox on entered date, so it update it correctly, but when running it via button it doesn't :( I use standard "insert" button and typing `UserForm1.Show`

Comment: [SOLVED] Added code to module instead of `UserForm_Initialize` and it's update list every time I change date. `UserForm1.Show` added at the end of the code.